# How to derive a coordinate system from distance measures to reference points

Tags: geometry

Problem: In a 3-dimensional space we can determine the position of a given point by measuring the distances to four known reference points ([like the GPS does](https://gisgeography.com/trilateration-triangulation-gps/#:%7E:text=Each%20satellite%20is%20at%20the,broadcast%20signals%20as%20a%20sphere.)) by intersecting the spheres of radius equal to the measured distances as they all four intersect in a single point, I am trying to figure out if given only the distances from an arbitrary random point chosen as origin to reference points for which we don't have coordinates, we can derive a coordinate system and place the reference points as coordinates in this system.

So far I managed to make it work for the 1-dimensional number line in the following way:

Let reference point A=1 and B=-3, we don't know this since we can only measure distances, the observer is at the origin 0 and he can only measure the distance to A (dA=1) and distance to B (dB=3), if we choose A to be in the positive direction then the position of A along the number line is obtained A=1, but we still don't know if B is 3 or -3.

[Blue is A, orange are possible positions for B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0xV0.png)

If we move in the direction of A (positive) by a small amount we can tell where is B by measuring the distance again, if distance to B increases then B is -3, if distance to B decreases then B is at 3. With this we know the positions of A and B with respect to the origin.

I was wondering if there is a way to apply a similar reasoning in 2 and 3 dimensions, that is given only distances from random positions to reference points with unknown positions, can we obtain a single possible way of placing the points in a 2D plane (or 3D space), considering that we can designate the orientation of the plane however we choose (which way is positive or forward), and we can also place the origin wherever is convenient. The idea is to be able to do it only by measuring distances to the references from random positions, not by measuring the distances between the reference points themselves, as done in the 1-dimensional example.

Sorry if this is a physics question, to me it seemed more pertinent to mathematics.

Comment: Super interesting question, and it seems this idea has been useful in multiple fields. Definitely physics , GPS. 

In neuroscience, there are multiple cases using this idea: Some neurons can signal your distance to a landmark in a inverse fashion (e.g. $exp(-d(p,x))$), then your neural system needs to figure out where you are based on this distance signal. 
In recording, multiple electrode could hear the "signal" from the same neuron, then you can use their relative amplitude on the electrodes to figure out the relative distance and find the location of neuron (to some extant).